# FileプラグインのAPIで「Uncaught TypeError: window.requestFileSystem is not a function」のエラーが発生する

Tags: android, monaca, cordova

Onsen UI V2 Angular 1 Splitterテンプレートを使って開発を始めました。
実行環境は Android です。

http://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_6.2/file/
http://poyo.hatenablog.jp/entry/2016/11/05/014205

を参考にCordovaプラグインのFileを有効にして、開発を進めているのですが、以下のエラーが出てファイル一覧が取得できません。

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.requestFileSystem is not a function
```

何をどうしたらエラーが出なくなるのか分からずに困っています。
コメントアウトは試行錯誤の跡として残してあります。
どうか助けをよろしくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html id="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/onsenui/js/angular-onsenui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //alert("Fileプラグインが利用できます。");
        window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
        //window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, error);
        var grantedBytes = 0;// 1024*1024*10; // 10MB
        window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, /*$scope.*/fileSystemReceived, /*$scope.*/errorHandler);
    }
    
    myApp = ons.bootstrap();
    myApp.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
        this.load = function(page) {
          $scope.splitter.content.load(page);
          $scope.splitter.left.close();
        };

        this.toggle = function() {
          $scope.splitter.left.toggle();
        };
      });

myApp.controller("SampleController", ["$scope", "FileSystem", function($scope, FileSystem){
  FileSystem.getFileSystem()
  .then(function(fs){
    $scope.ROOT_PATH = fs.root.toURL(); /* ルートへのパスを取得 */
  }, 
  function(error){
    alert("エラーです");
  });
  
    $scope.fileSystemReceived = function (fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("souvenirs.json", { create: true, exclusive: false }, $scope.fileEntryReceived, $scope.errorHandler);
    }

    $scope.fileEntryReceived = function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter($scope.fileWriterReceived, errorHandler);
    }

    $scope.fileWriterReceived = function (fileWriter) {
        var listeSouvenirsText = angular.toJson($scope.listeSouvenirs);
        fileWriter.write(listeSouvenirsText);
    }

    $scope.errorHandler = function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
  
}]);

myApp.factory("FileSystem", ["$q", function($q){
    return {
        getFileSystem: function(){
            let deferred = $q.defer();
            //window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
            
            var requestedBytes = 1024*1024*10; // 10MB
            navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (
                requestedBytes,
                function (grantedBytes) {
                    window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, /*$scope.*/fileSystemReceived, /*$scope.*/errorHandler);
                },
                /*$scope.*/errorHandler
            );
            /*
            window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, function(filesystem){
                deferred.resolve(filesystem);
            }, function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
            */
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        
    };
}]);

    function errorHandler(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    function fileSystemReceived(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("souvenirs.json", { create: true, exclusive: false }, $scope.fileEntryReceived, $scope.errorHandler);
    }
    
    ons.ready(function() {
        //console.log("Onsen UI is ready!");
        //window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <ons-splitter ng-controller="AppController as app" var="splitter">
    <ons-splitter-side side="left" width="220px" collapse swipeable>
      <ons-page>
        <ons-list>
          <ons-list-item ng-click="app.load('home.html')" tappable>
            Home
          </ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item ng-click="app.load('settings.html')" tappable>
            Settings
          </ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item ng-click="app.load('about.html')" tappable>
            About
          </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
      </ons-page>
    </ons-splitter-side>
    <ons-splitter-content page="test.html"></ons-splitter-content>
  </ons-splitter>

 <ons-template id="test.html" ng-controller="SampleController">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Test</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <h1>てすと</h1>
    <span>{{ROOT_PATH}}</span>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Android6.0の端末で試してみました。
CordovaのFileプラグインがインストールされていない場合に同じエラーが発生します。
[image: エラーログ]

この後にCorodvaのFileプラグインをインストールすることでエラーが発生しなくなりました。
正しくプラグインをインストールできているかご確認ください。

Comment: プラグインのインストールはクラウドIDEでのcordovaプラグインの管理ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: monacaのクラウドIEDを使用されている場合は、そうだと思います。エラー内容からFileプラグインが正しく適用されていないのではと考えました。ひょっとするとdevicereadyのイベント発火のタイミングではまだFileプラグインの準備ができていないのかもしれません。devicereadyイベントをfilePluginIsReadyイベントに変更して試してみてください。(またはtimeoutなどでwindow.requestFileSystemを遅延して実行させてみてください）

Comment: filePluginIsReadyに変えてもダメでした。  クラウドIDEを使わずにプラグインをインストールすると動くようなので、クラウドIDEの問題なのかもしれません。  クラウドIDEを使わない場合のインストール方法を知らないので、自分でも調べてみますが、教えてもらえると幸いです。

Comment: プラグインの使い方を知りたい（というより開発環境を変える）のであれば、質問内容が発散してしまうため別途質問を挙げたほうが良いと思います。私の回答は質問にあるエラーに対する解決方法なので。

Comment: 開発環境は変えたくないと思い、不具合として報告してみました。  ありがとうございました。